# Storing the data to Azure storage, blob or table?

Tags: sql, .net, azure, azure-storage

I have a Web app with database where the consumption data are stored in SQL database. I want to consolidate the data data older than 3 months to SQL database and save the unconsolidated data to storage. The data will not be often accessed because the consolidated info will be available in SQL it's only for purpose that somethink will go wrong. It is better to use table or blob storage? Thanks for your advices.

The data will be accesed separately or based on from which building they are comming. For example I have building A and someone comes and want to know the detailed consumption for a week or day half year ago. I will go to storage and get the data. The data in SQL are stored every 5 minutes.

Comment: Can you please share more details about how this data will be used. Answer would depend on that largely. Please edit your question and provide those details.

Comment: is it more clear now?

Comment: Much better now. Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you want to introduce a complex process to archive and unarchive data? I suggest instead that you keep your data as is for easy consistent access, but push the old data off on to cold (cheap) storage using elastic db. Costs less. Zero intervention required when accessing it

Comment: The assumption is that I will never use these data but I want to know what gonna happen if this problem will come because now they say somethink but after half year they could change the opinion. For now the data will not be accesible from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either blob storage or table storage for this purpose but I am more inclined towards using table storage to store this data.

The reason being you would want some kind of querying capability which is only offered by table storage. With blob storage, you would need to download all the relevant data on the client side, parse that data to create some kind of collection and then query that collection. With table storage, you can execute server-side queries.

If you're going with table storage, my recommendation would be to use `date/time` value (with date precision) as the `PartitionKey`. This will make searching for data by date/time much faster.

If you're going with blob storage, my recommendation would be to use a `Cool Storage` account for saving this data. Since you would rarely need this data, storing it in a `Cool Storage` account would be cheaper than a regular storage account.

Comment: My first opinion was to go with tbuilding identifier as the partition key and the datetime as row key you whink that it is better this way?

Comment: Will you always be querying on both `tbuilding` and `datetime`? If that's the case, then you can go with your approach.

Comment: yes in 99% and what about inserting into table storage? Will this two possibilitites have same performance?

Comment: Depends on how much data will be there in a single partition. I would still go with `PartitionKey` as `datetime` and `RowKey` as `tbuilding + some random value` because by doing so you will create more partitions with lesser data in each partition. Thus searches will be much faster.